Axios DELETE method blocked by CORS policy. What am I missing?
I know this has been asked a thousand times. I've went through each one of the answers and nothing seems to work, or I'm not asking the right questions.
I'm doing a small full-stack project. My backend is Node and Express running in port:8000. The relevant part (I think) is this:
AppDataSource.initialize()
.then(()=>{

    ...
    const app = express()

    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.use(cors({
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
        credentials: true,
        origin: ['localhost:3000'],
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
    }))

    ...
})

The front, running on localhost:3000, is ReactJS and uses axios. The relevant code is this one:
const deleteUser = async (id: number) => {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')){

            try {
                await axios.delete(`users/${id}`)
                setUsers(users.filter((u: UserType) => {
                    return u.id !== id
                }))
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e)
            }           
        }
    }

The backend delete:
export const DeleteUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    const repository =  AppDataSource.getRepository(User)
    const user = await repository.findOneBy({id})

    if (!user) {
        res.status(404).send({
            message: "No user found"
        })
    } else {
        await repository.delete(id)
        
        res.status(204).send({
            message: "User deleted"
        })
    }
}

In Chrome I get this:


I may add that I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin addon installed and active in Chrome, and Postman App has no issues DELETing records at all.
Any help?


Have you checked the network tab to see if axios is adding any additional headers? Also, could you try adding OPTIONS to the methods?

I added two more images. Not sure if that helps

Could you also share the api method for the delete?

Just added it to the post. But since Postman has no issues deleting, I assume it is the front? Chrome?

That delete method looks fine to me...

I'm having a hard time here, at first glance everything appears to be correct

I agree that disabling the extension might fix it.

Disabling the extension doesn't even allow a godam GET request. Dude, I hate this CORS so much. And I don't even know what it is

A shot in the dark, but could you send over what your postman request looks like from the UI?

localhost:3000 is not a valid Web origin. Try with origin: ['http://localhost:3000'].

I switched browser to FireFox, installed a CORS add-on and it worked. Doesn't solve the issue, but it does show the problem is Chrome.

Clearly very frustrating. I think you'll have to discover the root cause before it's production ready though...

It is. I honestly don't understand how at this point CORS is still an issue without an easy way to manage it. Security is important, but this is just getting in the way of developing since ancient times.

I'm not sure why DELETE is an issue considering your settings yet.
Temporarily set your configuration to
    allowedHeaders: '*',
    credentials: false,
    origin: '*',
    methods: '*'
}));

And see if the issue persists. If that doesn't work include all additional headers the front end is sending in the allowedHeaders.
Also ensure that you are not overriding the cors settings on the delete method.
Edit: Maybe the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Chrome add on is interfering. Consider disabling that or trying in a different browser.
Edit 2: Try changing to http://localhost:3000 from localhost:3000 The line doesn't actually need the brackets either since its one item. So this would work:
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
Edit 3: Try adding an additional step in the backend (after cors settings are set) to log the cors headers from the frontend and from postman (edit for typescript):
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('CORS headers:', res.getHeaders());
    next();
});

Edit 4: My final suggestion is to compare the network request on Chrome to your Postman request. 1) Headers, (Content-Type, Authorization, etc). Does Chrome send any extra? 2) Cookies and 3) URL. Check that they match exactly and that there isn't anything unusual or extra in the browser request.

I've tried that. But tried again just to make sure and still the same error

How do I check if I'm overriding something?

You would override the cors value for a specific route with a line like this:
app.delete('/users/:id', cors(), (req, res) => {

Can you try in a different browser where you don't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin add on? I am wondering if that is interfering.

Or maybe temporarily disabling the add on?

The OP appears to be sending an authorization header (I'm guessing that's why the allowlisted it in CORS). If that's the case, why credentials: false?

That was my first suggestion only because you cannot have origin: '*', with credentials set to true.
Ideally I believe it should look like this:
app.use(cors({         allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization' 'any other headers front end sends'],         credentials: true,         origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],         methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']     }))

Ah @RachelJoyce, good point - in that case, though the OP could just use origin reflection with this simpler configuration: app.use(cors({credentials:true,origin:true})), just to test to see if it works or if something else is going on (like they typo-d their URL on the FE or something silly). They have to have credentials set to true if they're sending them, right?

@RachelJoyce I had that config originally and same issue. Tried Safari just to check another browser, and didn't even let me GET the users.

I'm sorry. All these suggestions are guesses because your configuration does look correct. Can you send over what your request headers are in Chrome?

Just making sure. You do have a line that runs the application on port 8000. Right?
    app.listen(8000, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port 8000`);
    });


Yes. There is no typo or anything like that. It works perfectly fine in FireFox and Postman.

If this configuration doesn't work, then something else has gone wrong and you actually don't even have a CORS issue and it's a red herring, your requests from your browser are failing for a different reason (like you typo'd the URL or something, or the code that you think is running on 8000 isn't the code that's actually running on 8000):
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: true,
})

If that configuration does work, then start adding back in pieces of your config to find out where it fails.
Highly encourage you to check out the source code, it's a pretty trivial read, tbh:
https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js
